# Open and close AGAIN

Tags: german

Lets say you write an manual:

1. Open the window
2. Throw out a stone
3. Close the window

In German you could add again: Close the window **again**. / Schließen sie das Fenster **wieder**.
This does not mean: Do it twice, instead it emphasizes to revert your action. The word **wieder** means both, and here in this context it would be the second.

I am not sure if this is also right in English or if it would be a bad translation.

Note: The same can be used for: pick up and put down or stand up and sit down and many more.

Answer (score 2):

Not a trivial question. *Again* is an adverb. *Again* = *back to the original place or condition* or “*once more or **as before***”

[Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/again)

“Get some rest and you'll soon be well again.”

In your example “*Close the window again*”, it is difficult to regard *again* as an adverb qualifying *close*. Rather, it seems to refer adjectivally to the previous state of the window rather than to the verb.

Another viewpoint is that the sequence of events is: Window closed - window opened - window closed again; or Sitting - stood - sitting again. So perhaps “again” refers adverbially to  the unexpressed past participle adjectives such as *closed* in *window closed*.